# How to configure test in SpringBoot app when OAuth is used

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

My SpringBoot application acts as OAuth provider using spring annotations and properties file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class BioDare2WSApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BioDare2WSApplication.class, args);
    }        
}
```

And the app works.

But when I run tests with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` they fail unless `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation is added to the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BioDare2WSApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration //needed to prevent Failed to load ApplicationContext 
public class BioDare2WSApplicationTest {

    public BioDare2WSApplicationTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

If I omit @WebAppConfiguration the context load fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': 
    Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] ...
```

How could I configure the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter manaully so I don't have to put WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter on top of all my test classes.

I would like to have test "configuration" class that I could use during test (for example to setup test DB etc) like:

```
public class BioDare2TestConfiguration extends BioDare2WSApplication {
...
  HOW TO CONFIGURE IT SO not to have oauth exceptions
}
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BioDare2TestConfiguration.class)
public class BioDare2WSApplicationTest {
...
}
```

Adding @WebAppConfiguration on top of BioDare2TestConfiguration does not help. Such annotation has to be on the test class itself to work.